# Get 2 different L1 icache line sizes

Tags: cpu-cache

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and intel i5 450 on my PC.
I used two methods to get the cache line size of the level 1 instruction cache.
But results are different.

```
firo@snow:~/ws$ getconf LEVEL1_ICACHE_LINESIZE

32


firo@snow:~/ws$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/coherency_line_size 

64
```

Is there something wrong? It's so confused.

Comment: What do you get for `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/{level,type}`?

Comment: cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/{level,type}
1
Instruction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an Intel CPU and assuming standard Linux/glibc and no virtualization of `cpuid`...

The cache values reported from `getconf`/`sysconf()` come from glibc's  [i386/sysconf.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/sysconf.c;h=9896099c3bffd973629841555fc0db3c1528356c;hb=8fe89494e6516048759425ec30d8878a6233e00f#l459). The ones in sysfs come from [intel_cacheinfo.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/intel_cacheinfo.c#L_371).

The most obvious difference is that sysfs only returns values from `cpuid` 4, whereas `sysconf()` first looks at `cpuid` 2 and only checks `cpuid` 4 if one of the bytes is `0xFF`. There's a discrepancy between the entry for 0x09 in sysconf.c:

```
    { 0x09,  4, 32, M(_SC_LEVEL1_ICACHE_SIZE),   32768 },
```

and table 3-22 of the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf#page=628):

> 09H | Cache | 1st-level instruction cache: 32KBytes, 4-way set associative, 64 byte line size

so it looks like a bug in glibc.

Answer (score 0):

getconf returns a kernel configuration value, the semantics of which are determined by kernel code, while /sys is returning a physical characteristic of the cpu.  to understand the discrepancy, you need to examine how the kernel configuration variable is used in the kernel code.